# How to restore deleted Azure function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, restore

Accidentally deleted Azure function App from VS Code. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: Have you deleted the Function app resource ? if not, you can again `Publish` from VS. If you have deleted the func app resource itself, then you need to create it in Azure portal, and then do a Publish from VS.

Comment: Are you asking that you want to restore the Azure Functions App Project deleted from Visual Studio Code (locally)? If yes, identity where your VS Code deleted files are located at and then go to that folder > restore them!

Comment: Code is not deleted from local, function app is deleted

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to recreate the resource. App Services has some limited undelete capability, but this is currently available for Function Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-undelete